# iOS: Parse login for Facebook creating some hash in username field

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am signing up on Parse using Parse SDK for Facebook using following method.

- `[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: block:]`

Although this works successfully, but the resultant username field is some kind of hash value, does any one know its workaround?

- How can I get retrieve a proper username?
- Document or link that points to this hashing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct - the UserName-value is a hash made by Parse. If you use FB you don't have to worry about either that or the password. You can get the user's normal first and last name + all the other info if you use FBRequestConnection. Take a look at [this](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios).

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the this?

Comment: It's all very very nice described on parse.com and developers.facebook.com

Comment: I know thattt, I meant more about hashing of username.

Comment: What do you want? :-)

Comment: Well I simply want to retrieve the actual username, or perhaps a documented proof of hashing.

Comment: @AbubakrDar - 1. there's no such thing as an "actual username" in Facebook. Either you mean the user's name (first name + last name) or the unique Facebook ID. When you set up your FB user in Parse, they will use their standart User class and therefore fill out their 'username' and 'password' column with a parse-created unique string (the "hash") and a hidden value. These values should not be changed or used.

Comment: 2. when you have set up a user with Facebook in Parse, you can request all the data about the actual user from FB. There you can get the 'name', 'fbid', 'e-mail' etc. This is possible because you are logged in as a user and therefore you can use 'me' in the requests. Read more in the Parse guide or [here](https://parse.com/questions/when-sign-up-by-facebook-the-database-write-username-as-token-not-a-user-original-name)